# Html code auto fixed on staging, but not on prod

Tags: html, browser, hugo

I have a website built on Hugo, and while implementing a new feature, a mistake was made by improperly closing an `<iframe>` tag. Strangely, this error did not manifest itself on the staging environment, `<iframe>` tag was fixed (automatically by the browser I suppose) for users across different browsers and countries. However, on the production server, the incorrectly closed tag caused the layout to break. I’m unsure which direction to investigate to resolve the root of the issue. I do guess it has nothing to do with hugo.

1. I would appreciate it if you could suggest possible reasons why everything worked correctly on the staging environment and not on the production?
2. Is there some way to prevent auto fixing the tags from happening on staging, e.g.?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I would appreciate it if you could suggest possible reasons why everything worked correctly on the staging environment and not on the production?

Maybe you tested with different browsers.

> 2. Is there some way to prevent auto fixing the tags from happening on staging, e.g.?

Validate your HTML by using something like https://validator.w3.org/.